# Angular JS , putting the angular-1.2.27\docs\index.html to run

Tags: angularjs, installation

I'm starting to learn angularjs , but i found some things that didnt make sense for me. Im using chrome into a windows 8 machine.

First i downloaded the angularjs zip version from :  https://angularjs.org/

folowing i did unzip the files in some directory.

Then i wanted to just take a look into the documentation into angular-1.2.27\docs\index.html.

The result is weird ,the menus doesnt works, the screen takes a long time to load and let it with a loading message into the middle of it.

Does it needs to be in a server ? since its all about javascrit it shouldnt work all by himself?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…1%3Breturn%20n%7D%3B%20newVal%3A%20111859%3B%20oldVal%3A%20111858%22%5D%5D
angular.js:10103 Error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file://file:/C:/Users/nameduser/Documents/pessoal/angular/angular-1.2.27/docs/api' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.

Comment: im not sure, but i readed something about
http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/
i coulnd use this directive at work because of serveral restrictions.. @BenDiamant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for anybody that arives here, the question i raised was a misundestand of the Tutorial  and the other places i read about it.

In the case above, my mistake was that i suposed that i needed do run the npm install anywhere , but it should be run inside the project that needed the dependences that are related to.